# export special character in XML in a valid way

Tags: java, xml, special-characters

I want to export a sequence like the following in an XML file:

```
 <Cash & company>
```

but I export (with Java XML framework)

```
 <Cash &amp; company>
```

1st question:
Which sequence is correct regarding XML parsers? 1st one or second one ?

2nd question:
if

```
 <Cash &amp; company>
```

is not correct.
How to correct it? In fact, method `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(string)` doesn't make the export pretty.

Answer (score 2):

None of that is correct, and it cannot be corrected. You need to do something different.

The name of an element must be a `Name` as defined by the [XML Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#IDAKUDS), i.e. letters, digits, `:`, `_`, `-`, `.`, and `·`.

So, you *could* use `<Cash_and_company>`, but you wouldn't get `Cash & company` back when parsing it.

If you want the name to support all characters, store it in an attribute:

```xml
<Foo name="Cash &amp; company">
```